# How do I check if AutoIt3 executable is already running?

Tags: executable, autoit

After compiling my AutoIt v3 script into an EXE executable, I want to ensure that only one instance can be run at a time. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: [_Singleton](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Singleton.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [_Singleton](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Singleton.htm)

```
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

If _Singleton("test", 1) = 0 Then
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Warning", "An occurrence of test is already running")
    Exit
EndIf
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "OK", "the first occurrence of test is running")
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: I think the singleton function in the accepted answer is a more reliable approach. But I’ll leave this answer here in case it’s useful for anyone with older versions that might not have access to it or perhaps want a different approach.**

These lines of code will allow you to exit a script if it is already running.  It works best when the script is compiled into an EXE.  Be aware that if it's run as an uncompiled AU3 script it will quit if *any* AutoIt script is already running.

Hope this helps somebody.

```
#include <Process.au3>

; Quit with message box if app is already running
$numberOfAppInstances = ProcessList(_ProcessGetName(@AutoItPID))
$numberOfAppInstances = $numberOfAppInstances[0][0]
If $numberOfAppInstances > 1 Then
    MsgBox(0, "Exiting", "Application already running!")
    Exit
EndIf
```